# The sum Column in SoapUI Load Test Statistics Data

Tags: statistics, export, soapui, load-testing

I have a newbie question related to the Statistics data exported from SoapUI after a load test: one of the columns is labelled **sum** and I was wondered what data it contained. This column is right after the **err** column so I was wondering if it is related to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`err` is the number of errors in that sample

`sum` is the running total (sum) of errors

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I asked the same question in the SoapUI community and all I got was a link to documentation that didn't answer my question. Once again, SO comes through where others fall short...